# What is the correct way to implement Alpine.js and Phoenix 1.7 initialization with LiveView 0.18.3?

Tags: css, tailwind-css, phoenix-framework, alpine.js, phoenix-live-view

I'm having trouble getting Alpine and Phoenix LiveViews to work together.

With the code provided below, liveview `phx-click` events do not fire, but Alpine works. CSS animations specified by Tailwind do not activate as they should on page load, but other CSS properties specified by Tailwind do style elements correctly. There is a card on the page in question that is supposed to flip over on page load, but it just loads in and never flips.

If I remove `Alpine.start()`, alpine does *not* work correctly on page load, but does start working after I follow a liveview component link on this page that looks like this: `<.link navigate={~p"/lessons"}>`. All Tailwind css, including animations, works correctly. Notably, some of Alpine *is indeed* working on page load. The element on the page with `x-show="open"` is hidden because its parent has `x-data="{ open: false }"`. The `@click="open - !open"` does in fact change the value of `open`. What's broken is the way that `x-show` does not alter the `display: none` property as the value of `open` changes.

If I remove `liveSocket.connect()`, alpine works on page load, but of course then liveviews don't work. The card never flips. It just loads in overturned. I don't understand why removing the socket connection disrupts the CSS.

If I move `Alpine.start()` to just *after* `liveSocket.connect()`. Alpine does not work on page load, but all Tailwind css and liveview functionality works correctly.

Inscrutably (to me), if I remove *both* `Alpine.start()` and `liveSocket.connect()`, Alpine **works just fine** on page load, but also here of course liveviews don't work.

I'm having a tough time searching for what `Alpine.start()` actually does, and worse, I'm struggling to understand its interactions with `liveSocket.connect()`.

---

Relevant portion from `app.js`

```
import Alpine from '../vendor/alpine'
window.Alpine = Alpine
Alpine.start()

let csrfToken = document.querySelector("meta[name='csrf-token']").getAttribute("content")
let liveSocket = new LiveSocket("/live", Socket, {
    params: { _csrf_token: csrfToken },
    hooks: Hooks,
    dom: {
        onBeforeElUpdated(from, to) {
            if (from._x_dataStack) {
                window.Alpine.clone(from, to)
            }
        }
    },
})

// connect if there are any LiveViews on the page
liveSocket.connect()
```

Relevant portion from `nav.ex`, a live componennt

```
<div class="relative ml-3" x-data="{ open: false }">
  <button
    @click="open = !open"
    @click.outside="open = false"
    type="button"
    class="flex max-w-xs items-center rounded-full bg-white text-sm focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-green focus:ring-offset-2"
    id="user-menu-button"
    aria-expanded="false"
    aria-haspopup="true"
  >
    <span class="sr-only">Open user menu</span>
    <img
      class="h-8 w-8 rounded-full"
      src="https://i.kym-cdn.com/photos/images/facebook/001/431/201/40f.png"
      alt=""
    />
  </button>
  <!--
    Dropdown menu, show/hide based on menu state.
  -->
  <div
    class="absolute right-0 z-10 mt-2 w-48 origin-top-right rounded-md bg-white py-1 shadow-lg ring-1 ring-black ring-opacity-5 focus:outline-none"
    role="menu"
    aria-orientation="vertical"
    aria-labelledby="user-menu-button"
    tabindex="-1"
    x-show="open"
    x-transition:enter="transition ease-out duration-100"
    x-transition:enter-start="transform opacity-0 scale-95"
    x-transition:enter-end="transform opacity-100 scale-100"
    x-transition:leave="transition ease-in duration-75"
    x-transition:leave-start="transform opacity-100 scale-100"
    x-transition:leave-end="transform opacity-0 scale-95"
    x-cloak
  >...</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was due to the context in which the live component was rendered. The live component was being rendered outside of a live view, which is not allowed.

I changed the live component in `nav.ex` to a regular `Phoenix.Component`. Then I removed the following lines from `app.js`:

```
window.Alpine = Alpine
Alpine.start()
```

I kept the Alpine import line `import Alpine from '../vendor/alpine'`

With those changes, I have working Alpine, liveview, and CSS on page load.

Comment: I will leave this question open because I'm not satisfied with just having a solution; I want to use this as a learning opportunity, and I don't understand what's happening here yet.

Comment: Ah ok, I understand now. Turns out the live component was being rendered outside of the context of a live view, and that's the reason for the inconsistent behavior. I would have guessed that it wouldn't have rendered at all, but it did.